# How to convert a datagridview to an objects list?

Tags: c#, list, object, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is having two columns. Each row is containing a record. I want to get each record to a list of objects.. Each row is having two values and I want to get those two values to two object attributes. Row has values id and name I want to read the values to obj.id and obj.name.

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code samples in your question, it is hard to guess how you have populated your `DataGridView`. However, here are 2 likely scenarios:

Assuming you bound your `DatagridView` to a `DataTable`:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
DataTable dt = DataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
    myObject.id = (int)row["Id"]; // Assuming the column is called "Id"
    myObject.Name = (string)row["Name"];// Assuming the column is called "Name"
    list.Add(myObject);
}
```

Or, you can access the data grid view directly:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
    myObject.id = (int)row.Cells["Id"].Value; // Assuming the column is called "Id"
    myObject.Name = (string)row.Cells["Name"].Value;// Assuming the column is called "Name"
    list.Add(myObject);
}
```

As I said, those are just examples as you may have used a strong typed DataTable or any other type of  Datasource, but still, the main Idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
List<Class1> List1 = new List<Class>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView.Rows)
{
     List1.Add(new Class1(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
}
```